# Mock a global object with Jest and Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I have a React component. For good or bad, I use the `Routes` global object exposed by `js-routes` - a gem for Rails. I have a snapshot test using Jest which tests my simple component that happens to use the `Routes` global.

In my test I want to mock `Routes`. So when my component calls `Routes.some_path()`, I can just return some arbitrary string.

The error that I mainly get is `Cannot find name 'Routes'.`.

Here is my setup:

**package.json**

```
"jest": {
  "globals": {
    "ts-jest": {
      "enableTsDiagnostics": true
    }
  },
  "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
  "setupFiles": [
    "<rootDir>/app/javascript/__tests__/setupRoutes.ts"
  ]
...
```

**setupRoutes.ts** (This seemed like the most popular solution)

```
const globalAny:any = global;

globalAny.Routes = {
  some_path: () => {},
};
```

**myTest.snapshot.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';

import MyComponent from 'MyComponent';

describe('My Component', () => {
  let component;

  beforeEach(() => {
    component = shallow(<MyComponent />);
  });

  it('should render correctly', () => {
    expect(toJson(component)).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

**MyComponent.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as DOM from 'react-dom';

class MyComponent extends React.Component<{}, {}> {

  render() {
    return <div>{Routes.some_path()}</div>;
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

If I `console.log(window)` in the test, `Routes` does exist. So I'm not sure why it doesn't like `Routes` being used int he component. In fact it must be Typescript thinking it doesn't exist but at run time it does.
I guess my question then is how can I tell Typescript to chill out about `Routes`?

Answer (score 8):

In **setupRoutes.ts**

```
(global as any).Routes = {
  some_path: () => {}
};
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I still get `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Routes'`. Can you provide a small working example?